# Artifactory cache file shows much larger size than its source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, caching, artifactory, mirror

I have set up artifactory cache 
( without active replication ) and the file size after first cache is 3 times the size of actual source file. I tried to zap it multiple times and even flush the source but dosnt help.
what may be going wrong ?

Comment: Is this happening for a specific file? did you compare the content and checksum of the cachee files vs the original one?

Answer (score 0):

so one thing i figured that adding apache http service to the source is causing this. Still debugging.